# Deleting an object field before saving using django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

The following code uses a form to save a new user avatar picture, however I cannot get this to delete the delete the old avatar and update with the new on. I've tried many different code variations.

Could someone point me in the correct direction. An explanation on why this is happening and brief example would be very helpful. All help is greatly appreciated.

model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
avatar = Image..................
```

view

```
@login_required
def profile(request, pk):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=pk)
    pf = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
    if request.method =="POST":
        if pf.is_valid():
            profile.avatar.delete() #doesn't work
            pf.save()

    return render_to_response('template.html', {
        'profile': profile,
        'pf':pf
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ pf }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships act like the `objects` attribute. `MyModel.objects.delete()` wouldn't work either. You need to do something like `profile.avatar.all().delete()`

**UPDATE:** The above applies to many-to-many relationships. `delete()` can be accessed directly off a foreign key.

When deleting a foreign key, though, Django removes the associated database row and nullifies the foreign key's `pk`/`id` attribute, but it does *not* clear out the data for the foreign key immediately. You could technically, do something like:

```
profile.avatar.delete()
profile.avatar.save()
```

And, you would end up with the same object, only with a different primary key.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Django. Can you please explain a little further to help me understand. what you mean mean? Surely the required image has been located using the line "profile = Profile.objects.get(user=pk)" and profile.avatar. I seem to be getting no attribute named all using your suggestion.

Comment: I'm also receiving the following: manager inst accessible via profile instances. I could save first then delete however that would make things more difficult locating the correct image?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed since `delete` wasn't working that you were actually dealing with a many-to-many relationship. If `avatar` is just a foreign key, then `delete` should be working. However, it's important to realize that `profile.avatar` will retain it's data for the life of the request (due to query caching), but if you test `profile.avatar.pk` it should be null, showing that it doesn't actually exist any more.

Comment: Almost there thank you very much for all your help. Greatly appreciated. Lastly, I'm being asked to supply two more arguments because only one is given. So its deleting the pk, user which is the FK and the associated avatar however I only want to delete/save the current/new avatar without touching the user or PK. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're merely modifying the avatar you can just do `profile.avatar.save()` but if you're actually replacing the avatar, you must do `profile.save()` to have the changes commit. Think of it as whichever object owns the attribute being modified must be saved.